# What is the information content of a single-particle system?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

I'm trying to better understand how information is quantified in the case of a closed system containing a single (fundamental) particle located at position $\vec{r}$ and traveling with a velocity $\vec{v}$. (Imagine that nothing else exists in this system and the only properties of this fundamental particle are position and velocity.) Is asking about the information content even meaningful here?

I have seen the approach of Shannon entropy, which links information content to the minimum number of yes/no questions needed to completely describe the state of the system, so does that mean the information content here would be 2 bits?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Apply e.g. [this idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) to [the phase space PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(physics)).

Answer (score 1):

The information we need to specify the particle in the box is its exact position and its momentum (the direction of the vector, since the magnitude of $\mathbf{p}$ is fixed). To "count" this information, divide the box into tiny volume elements, and within each element divide the sphere around the element to solid angles, so we may say that the particle in volume element $i$ and is solid angle $j$  of that element, or $s_{i,j}$ for short. Suppose the total number of states $s_{i,j}$ is $\Omega$. Ignoring Boltzmann's constant the entropy is
$$S = \ln \Omega$$
In this construction $\Omega$ is the total number of possible states, all of which are equiprobable. The situation is entirely analogous to a fair die with $\Omega$ sides -- its entropy is $S=\ln \Omega$.

To write an actual formula,
$$
   \Omega(E,V,N) = 
   \frac{V^N}{h^{3n}} 
   \frac{(2\pi m E)^{3N/2}}{(\frac{3N}{2}-1)!}\frac{\Delta E}{E}
$$
which applies to $N$ particles with energy $E$ in a box with volume $V$